# After create record flow error

Tags: visual-workflow, after-trigger

I have an after insert flow that fires on opportunity.
[image]

I have a test class that needs to create an opportunity.

```
    public static Account CreateAccount (){
    Account newAcc = new Account ();
    newAcc.name = 'Test Account Name';
    newAcc.BillingCountry = 'United States';
    newAcc.Industry = 'Finance';
    newAcc.Account_Category__c = 'Commercial';
    insert newAcc;
    system.debug('newAcc.id:: ' + newAcc.Id);
    return newAcc;
}
```

And Also a CreateOpportunity

```
    public static Opportunity CreateOpportunity(){
    Account newAcc = CreateAccount();
    Opportunity oppNew = new Opportunity();
    oppNew.RecordTypeId = '0124H000000seDZQAY';
    oppNew.Name = 'Test Opp';
    oppNew.CloseDate = System.now().date();
    oppNew.StageName = 'New';
    oppNew.account = newAcc;
    insert oppNew;
    return oppNew;
}
```

However, when the test class is executed, I get an error on the testmethod:

> 13:27:28:404 EXCEPTION_THROWN [52]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, We can't save this record because the “After Insert - Opportunity” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. **An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow**
> An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow.  Please contact your system administrator for more information.: []

The log shows the following error, mentioning that the field: Account_Category__c is not set.
But it exists in the create record:

> 13:27:28:396 FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR The flow failed to access the value for Get_Account_Category_from_Account.Account_Category__c because it hasn't been set or assigned.|FlowDecision|No_Account_Category_For_Errors

The Account insert is successful, as shown in the log entry:

> 16:41:13:052 USER_DEBUG [32]|DEBUG|newAcc.id:: 0017E00001DY8XZQA1

Being around computers for many years:: Where's my mistake?
What's wrong with the flow of data in this scenario?

Tried as in the suggested edit: Error: Illegal assignment from Id to Account
[image]

---

I added a debug print, just before the insert oppNew
[image]
Looks like the 'Account Category' exists.

---

---

I think the error is that the 'After Insert' Flow - does not recognize the Account object. Even that the account was created before.

Comment: Seems like `Get_Account_Category_from_Account` is not set. Sharing the details of the node that tries to get said account might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try passing just the newAcc.Id to the oppNew in the create new opportunity APEX snippet.

oppNew.accountid = newAcc.Id;

I think this is the core of the issue.

Comment: i think you meant `oppNew.AccountId = newAcc.Id`

Comment: Yes it is AccountId, my bad

Comment: Thank you for the offer, but that's not it: I get error: 'Illegal assignment from Id to Account' (picture added to OP)

Comment: Did you tried this, exactly. oppNew.AccountId = newAcc.Id

Comment: Take into consideration the first comment of cropredy

Comment: Please update the field oppNew.AccountId and NOT oppNew.Account

Comment: @Saariko Please update the field oppNew.AccountId and NOT oppNew.Account